# Facebook FQL app access token needs permissions to access public data?

Tags: facebook, node.js, facebook-fql

Using [fbgraph](https://github.com/criso/fbgraph), I authenticate a local script and retrieve an app access token, which I then use to perform this query:

```
SELECT post_id, message, share_count, comment_info, like_info, created_time
FROM stream
WHERE source_id = USER_ID
AND actor_id = USER_ID
```

The user in question is a public page, specifically Oreo. Visiting their page takes no permissions, but this query using my app access token yields nothing. Specifically, this:

```
{ data: [] }
```

Do I need permissions to view public data? If so, how do I get them for the app without implementing a user authentication flow?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the access token.

Add the access_token to your query and see if it works!

try to use the token in fql tool and see if it works

Comment: I have the access token. When I print it out and use it in the FQL tool, I still get `{ data: [] }`.

Comment: witch SDK are you using (JS) , if so are you on localhost ??

Comment: fbgraph (https://github.com/criso/fbgraph). I'm running a local script, but it doesn't use a webserver, localhost or otherwise.

Comment: Ok , try to use it on your profile fetch your fb data and check if the sdk responded with any errors